ESP32S3 Dev Kit keeps crashing when trying to receive serial commands
I'm trying to use a code I got from the internet to control 2 motors by receiving commands through serial communication, the goal is to have the ESP32 connected with a Raspberry Pi 4 that's running ROS2 Foxy in Ubuntu 20.04. I modified the code a bit to work with the ESP32 since it was made for arduino boards (I'm also using ZS-X11H BLDC motor drivers since I'm using hoverboard motors). I'm getting this in the serial monitor:
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3818,len:0x508
load:0x403c9700,len:0x4
load:0x403c9704,len:0xad0
load:0x403cc700,len:0x29e4
entry 0x403c9880
ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
/*********************************************************************
 *  ROSArduinoBridge
 
    A set of simple serial commands to control a differential drive
    robot and receive back sensor and odometry data. Default 
    configuration assumes use of an Arduino Mega + Pololu motor
    controller shield + Robogaia Mega Encoder shield.  Edit the
    readEncoder() and setMotorSpeed() wrapper functions if using 
    different motor controller or encoder method.

    Created for the Pi Robot Project: http://www.pirobot.org
    and the Home Brew Robotics Club (HBRC): http://hbrobotics.org
    
    Authors: Patrick Goebel, James Nugen

    Inspired and modeled after the ArbotiX driver by Michael Ferguson
    
    Software License Agreement (BSD License)

    Copyright (c) 2012, Patrick Goebel.
    All rights reserved.

    Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
    modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
    are met:

     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above
       copyright notice, this list of conditions and/or other materials
       provided with the distribution.

    THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
    "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
    LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS
    FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
    INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
    BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
    LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
    CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
    LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN
    ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
 *  POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *********************************************************************/

#define USE_BASE      // Enable the base controller code
// #undef USE_BASE     // Disable the base controller code

/* Define the motor controller and encoder library you are using */
#ifdef USE_BASE
   /* The Pololu VNH5019 dual motor driver shield */
   //#define POLOLU_VNH5019

   /* The Pololu MC33926 dual motor driver shield */
   //#define POLOLU_MC33926

   /* The RoboGaia encoder shield */
   //#define ROBOGAIA
   
   /* Encoders directly attached to Arduino board */
   #define ARDUINO_ENC_COUNTER

   /* ZS-X11H Motor driver*/
   #define ZS_X11H_MOTOR_DRIVER
#endif

//#define USE_SERVOS  // Enable use of PWM servos as defined in servos.h
#undef USE_SERVOS     // Disable use of PWM servos

/* Serial port baud rate */
#define BAUDRATE     115200

/* Maximum PWM signal */
#define MAX_PWM        255

#include <Arduino.h>

/* Include definition of serial commands */
#include "commands.h"

/* Sensor functions */
#include "sensors.h"

/* Include servo support if required */
#ifdef USE_SERVOS
   #include <Servo.h>
   #include "servos.h"
#endif

#ifdef USE_BASE
  /* Motor driver function definitions */
  #include "motor_driver.h"

  /* Encoder driver function definitions */
  #include "encoder_driver.h"

  /* PID parameters and functions */
  #include "diff_controller.h"

  /* Run the PID loop at 30 times per second */
  #define PID_RATE           30     // Hz

  /* Convert the rate into an interval */
  const int PID_INTERVAL = 1000 / PID_RATE;
  
  /* Track the next time we make a PID calculation */
  unsigned long nextPID = PID_INTERVAL;

  /* Stop the robot if it hasn't received a movement command
   in this number of milliseconds */
  #define AUTO_STOP_INTERVAL 2000
  long lastMotorCommand = AUTO_STOP_INTERVAL;
#endif

/* Variable initialization */

// A pair of varibles to help parse serial commands (thanks Fergs)
int arg = 0;
int cmdIndex = 0;

// Variable to hold an input character
char chr;

// Variable to hold the current single-character command
char cmd;

// Character arrays to hold the first and second arguments
char argv1[16];
char argv2[16];

// The arguments converted to integers
long arg1;
long arg2;

/* Clear the current command parameters */
void resetCommand() {
  cmd = NULL;
  memset(argv1, 0, sizeof(argv1));
  memset(argv2, 0, sizeof(argv2));
  arg1 = 0;
  arg2 = 0;
  arg = 0;
  cmdIndex = 0;
}

/* Run a command.  Commands are defined in commands.h */
int runCommand() {
  int i = 0;
  char *p = argv1;
  char *str;
  int pid_args[4];
  arg1 = atoi(argv1);
  arg2 = atoi(argv2);
  
  switch(cmd) {
  case GET_BAUDRATE:
    Serial0.println(BAUDRATE);
    break;
  case ANALOG_READ:
    Serial0.println(analogRead(arg1));
    break;
  case DIGITAL_READ:
    Serial0.println(digitalRead(arg1));
    break;
  case ANALOG_WRITE:
    analogWrite(arg1, arg2);
    Serial0.println("OK"); 
    break;
  case DIGITAL_WRITE:
    if (arg2 == 0) digitalWrite(arg1, LOW);
    else if (arg2 == 1) digitalWrite(arg1, HIGH);
    Serial0.println("OK"); 
    break;
  case PIN_MODE:
    if (arg2 == 0) pinMode(arg1, INPUT);
    else if (arg2 == 1) pinMode(arg1, OUTPUT);
    Serial0.println("OK");
    break;
  case PING:
    Serial0.println(Ping(arg1));
    break;
#ifdef USE_SERVOS
  case SERVO_WRITE:
    servos[arg1].setTargetPosition(arg2);
    Serial0.println("OK");
    break;
  case SERVO_READ:
    Serial0.println(servos[arg1].getServo().read());
    break;
#endif
    
#ifdef USE_BASE
  case READ_ENCODERS:
    Serial0.print(readEncoderLeft());
    Serial0.print(" ");
    Serial0.println(readEncoderRight());
    break;
   case RESET_ENCODERS:
    resetEncoders();
    resetPID();
    Serial0.println("OK");
    break;
  case MOTOR_SPEEDS:
    /* Reset the auto stop timer */
    lastMotorCommand = millis();
    if (arg1 == 0 && arg2 == 0) {
      setMotorSpeeds(0, 0);
      resetPID();
      moving = 0;
    }
    else moving = 1;
    leftPID.TargetTicksPerFrame = arg1;
    rightPID.TargetTicksPerFrame = arg2;
    Serial0.println("OK"); 
    break;
  case MOTOR_RAW_PWM:
    /* Reset the auto stop timer */
    lastMotorCommand = millis();
    resetPID();
    moving = 0; // Sneaky way to temporarily disable the PID
    setMotorSpeeds(arg1, arg2);
    Serial0.println("OK"); 
    break;
  case UPDATE_PID:
    while ((str = strtok_r(p, ":", &p)) != nullptr) {
       pid_args[i] = atoi(str);
       i++;
    }
    Kp = pid_args[0];
    Kd = pid_args[1];
    Ki = pid_args[2];
    Ko = pid_args[3];
    Serial0.println("OK");
    break;
#endif
  default:
    Serial0.println("Invalid Command");
    break;
  }
  yield(); // Add yield to allow other tasks to run
}

/* Setup function--runs once at startup. */
void setup() {
  Serial0.begin(BAUDRATE);

// Initialize the motor controller if used */
#ifdef USE_BASE
  initMotorController();
  resetPID();
  initEncoders();  // Initialize encoders
#endif

/* Attach servos if used */
  #ifdef USE_SERVOS
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N_SERVOS; i++) {
      servos[i].initServo(
          servoPins[i],
          stepDelay[i],
          servoInitPosition[i]);
    }
  #endif
}

/* Enter the main loop.  Read and parse input from the serial port
   and run any valid commands. Run a PID calculation at the target
   interval and check for auto-stop conditions.
*/
void loop() {
  while (Serial0.available() > 0) {
    
    // Read the next character
    chr = Serial0.read();

    // Terminate a command with a CR
    if (chr == 13) {
      if (arg == 1) argv1[cmdIndex] = NULL;
      else if (arg == 2) argv2[cmdIndex] = NULL;
      runCommand();
      resetCommand();
    }
    // Use spaces to delimit parts of the command
    else if (chr == ' ') {
      // Step through the arguments
      if (arg == 0) arg = 1;
      else if (arg == 1)  {
        argv1[cmdIndex] = NULL;
        arg = 2;
        cmdIndex = 0;
      }
      continue;
    }
    else {
      if (arg == 0) {
        // The first arg is the single-letter command
        cmd = chr;
      }
      else if (arg == 1) {
        // Subsequent args are the command parameters
        argv1[cmdIndex] = chr;
        cmdIndex++;
      }
      else if (arg == 2) {
        argv2[cmdIndex] = chr;
        cmdIndex++;
      }
    }
    yield(); // Add yield to allow other tasks to run
  }

#ifdef USE_BASE
  /* Are we due for another PID calculation? */
  if (millis() > nextPID) {
    updatePID();
    nextPID += PID_INTERVAL;
  }
  
  /* Have we exceeded the auto-stop interval? */
  if ((millis() - lastMotorCommand) > AUTO_STOP_INTERVAL) {
    setMotorSpeeds(0, 0);
    resetPID();
    moving = 0;
  }
  yield(); // Add yield to allow other tasks to run
#endif
}

Been looking online for solutions, like adding yield() or using Serial0 instead of Serial, but no fix. It's 5 am and I'm in desperate need of a solution, I need to show this project in 2 weeks to pass my mobile robotics class, the pressure build-up is insane. Here's the main code, for the other files of the program, they're attached in a .zip file in this discussion (https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/discussions/9993) since I don't want to have to show a humongous text.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Have you tried to use SoftwareSerial library, for ESP32 there is specific library named: https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial
I hope this will solve problem, good luck!
